# Literal vs variable with spaces on divide operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, division, literals

Let's say I have a literal Fixnum `1420028751000` and I want to convert using this:

```
Time.at(1420028751000 / 1000) # => 2014-12-31 20:25:51 +0800
```

I can put spaces also, let's say I am beginner and my coding is bad:

```
Time.at(1420028751000      /     1000)
Time.at(1420028751000 /1000)
```

All these work fine and give me correct result.

However, once I introduced variable:

```
a = 1420028751000
Time.at(a/1000)   # => Works!
Time.at(a / 1000) # => Works!
Time.at(a /1000)  # => Strange thing happen
```

My question is, what is so unique about the `/1000` that make it not working when introducing an variable in Ruby?

Comment: Just to be clear, there's nothing wrong with the code, it's just a characteristic of interpreters like `IRB`, as @ChrisHeald explains. All is well from the command line: `ruby -e "require 'time'; a = 1420028751000; p Time.at(a /1000)" #=> 2014-12-31 04:25:51 -0800`

Comment: Oh I actually encounter this error when my co-worker is working on an ERB Rails template with `<%=  %>`, guess is depend on context environment, tks for highlight Cary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's parser is interpreting `/1000` as the beginning of a literal regexp, since `a` is a token which may be a method. That is, imagine that `a` is a method:

```
def a(arg); end

Time.at(a /1000)
```

Ruby will interpret this as "a invoked with an incomplete regexp as the argument". To "complete" this call, Ruby is expecting you might want to do something like:

```
Time.at( a(/1000/) )
```

Comment: Got it, makes sense when you mention the incompleteness of the regexp, no wonder IRB is sort of like waiting for more thing to enter, tks Chris :)